# How to split a json response into different columns with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split a json response in pandas into different columns, so far I have this but I don't find an effective way how to do it, I already tried several solutions but I can't separate the object correctly.

This is a sample of the data

```
 {
  "codeId": "fc-5599",
  "financeInfo": [
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "totalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "totalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "totalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "totalReturn": 0.022425456852
    },
    {
      "date": "2022-01-30",
      "totalReturn": 0.022425456852
    }
  ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns = ["codeId","financeInfo"])
df.to_csv('data_fin.csv', index=False)
```

I have this:

[example of what I have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6db1N.png)

[example of the output I want to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sbyp.png)

Any idea of how improve this code?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using read_json() to covert this json to a pandas dataframe

```
    df = pd.read_json(json_name)
```

The documentation for it can be found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html